# Plotly - Pie chart with percentage and one decimal case

Tags: python, plotly, percentage

I'm having trouble while setting the labels of my pie chart (plotly Global Object) to percentage with only 1 decimal place.

[When I set texttemplate = "%{percent}"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8IkE.png)

[with texttemplate = "%{percent:.1f}"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YKGe.png)

My code right now:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=X,
    values=Y,
    textfont = {'family': "Montserrat"},
    texttemplate = "%{percent:.1f}",
    marker = {'colors': paleta, 'line':{'color': 'white', 'width':2}}
    )])
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value', textfont_size=10, sort=True,
    direction='clockwise', rotation = 0)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Don't post relevant info as links to images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a f:

```py
% ipython                                                            22-07-22 - 22:32:24
Python 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from decimal import Decimal

In [2]: percent = Decimal('5.323')

In [3]: "%{percent:.1f}"
Out[3]: '%{percent:.1f}'

In [4]: f"%{percent:.1f}"
Out[4]: '%5.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the time Waket Zheng, but I've got an error as  `percent` was not defined.

After reading [texttemplate documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/pie/#pie-texttemplate) I've found out that it was needed to change the syntax of the parameter:

Instead of
`texttemplate = "%{percent:.1f}"`

Using
`texttemplate = "%{value:.1%}"`